# error tomcat-jdbc.jar starting a app in tomcat6

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat6

im trying to deploy a web-app in tomcat6 with Mysql connection, i manually uploaded a tomcat-jdbc file v1.1.0.1 into `tomcat/lib/` but the app will not start,

copied the last lines of the log file here:

```
Mar 2, 2013 11:10:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 2, 2013 11:15:36 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:243)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:176)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:653)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:595)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:458)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:130)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:99)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:499)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:222)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1028)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:238)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:236)
        ... 40 more
Mar 2, 2013 11:15:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener
addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException:
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Mar 2, 2013 11:15:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 2, 2013 11:15:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

====

this is my contex.xml file

```
<Resource name="jdbc/AmbraDS"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username="test"
    password="test"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
```

and the jar file which is used is:

```
 apache-tomcat-jdbc-1.1.0.1-src
```

it seems there is a problem connecting with MySQL
can anybody help me through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the jdbc driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

It needs to be in catalinahome/lib

Comment: i did this too, the file is named mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
is it right?

Comment: Did you restart tomcat afterwards?

Comment: it used this scripts:
/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

Comment: Note for new users to tomcat: this is a different "lib" folder than the one in your app. It's a lib folder used by tomcat itself to load jars it needs to load things. So don't put the jdbc connection jar in your apps lib folder. It won't work there for this purpose!

Answer (score 0):

I think some conflict is there. For example if you have 2 locations and one has JDBC drivers and the other one not then if your classloader loads from the 1st location and some class from the 1st location wants to use the driver - the driver is not there. So look for the duplicate JARs that are using your driver

Comment: i did this before but i got the same log file

Comment: you have not added appropriate jar files.

Comment: how can i find  appropriate jar files and then upload them?

Comment: apache-tomcat-jdbc-1.1.0.1

Comment: you need to use mysql connector j driver

Comment: is used this mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar is it right?